# What amp rating fuse should be used for the low-voltage side of the control board in my Goodman furnace?

Tags: hvac, circuit-breaker, furnace, air-conditioning

I have a Goodman furnace (model `GMH80803BNBC`) (with separate Goodman AC condenser).
The specs (PDF) are [located online](https://www.goodmanmfg.com/pdfviewer.aspx?pdfurl=docs/librariesprovider6/default-document-library/ss-gmh82d2d460022fa6258827eff0a00754798.pdf?view=true).
The control board has stamped on it, next to the fuse (for the low-voltage (24V) portion), `5 AMP MAX`.
But I cannot find in the specs, online, or elsewhere on the board what the "recommended"(not the maximum) amp rating fuse is.

Do I assume a 3 Amp fuse should be used (as that appears to be the most common rating I've come across while searching online)?
There are no additional accessories wired to / being supplied by the board besides  a "regular" (not smart/wi-fi) programmable Honeywell thermostat.

**A little back story:**
Yesterday, one of the inside units would not run and there was no power to the t-stat.
Upon entering the attic to inspect the unit, I discovered a discarded 3 Amp fuse (which was blown) on the floor.
The 3 Amp fuse still in the control board was also blown.
I am left to assume the (discarded) fuse must have blown when the installers were testing the unit (or some point before we took ownership of the house -- this is a new build house, which we've been in for about 1.5 years).
This makes me wonder, in conjunction with the `5 AMP MAX` on the board, that perhaps a 5 Amp fuse should be used instead of 3 Amp?

The house has a second Goodman furnace (model `GMS80603ANBE`) (also with a separate Goodman AC condenser), which has a 3 Amp fuse, but the control board has nothing stamped on it about the max rating.
We've had no problems with this unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that [this document](https://www.questargas.com/ForEmployees/qgcOperationsTraining/Furnaces/Goodman_GMH8-GDH8-DualSaver-Gas-Furnace-Installation-Instructions.pdf) is for your unit and it indicates a 3amp fuse. Refer page 29, the trouble shooting section, top row, 5th column

[image]

Comment: That does appear to be for my unit, thanks!